# Adding x axis increment in plot() in R

Tags: r, plot

I plotted a graph in R using the plot function. I need the X axis to increment by 40 and y-axis to increment by 10.  I know we can specify increment by using seq function like this `x<-seq(-200, 200, by=40)`. But how do I add this info in plot function. Please help me.

Here is my code

```
p<-U %*% Sigma
plot(p)
```

Below is my graph. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot(p, xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=seq(-200,200,40))
```